# Transferring specific Info from one spreadsheet to another in Excel

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, formulas

I am a complete beginner in Microsoft Excel and am attempting to create a workplace Time Sheet where you enter information regarding your shift (times, who you worked with, etc.) and that information is automatically copied to Invoices within other spreadsheet tabs:
[image: TimeSheet view]
(names made up for confidentiality purposes obviously).

The goal is for each name entered (ie. Charlie, Joseph, etc.) to have their own invoices and only the information regarding that name listed in the time sheet is transferred to their appropriate invoice tab:
[image: Invoice View]

For example - We see the name Charlie twice in the timesheet. How would we make it so the name on one of the invoice tabs says "This invoice is for services rendered to Charlie" and add ONLY Charlie's information (work times, hours, date) into the cells on that invoice? And do the same for the other names?

Please let me know if this is even possible or if I'm being unclear in what I'm attempting.

Comment: It looks feasible with formulas. You need to write formulas is a sufficient number of rows in the invoice, something like `IFERROR(INDEX(MATCH...))` and grab the appropriate rows from the time sheet. The Total field is then calculated simply in the invoice. I wonder also if it can be done with pivot tables.

Comment: Hmm something like IFERROR(Invoice(Charlie))? I'm not quite sure how to format it. Also, the order of the names will vary depending on the timesheet, so would that formula still work if the names change positions on the time sheet? Thank you for your input

Answer (score 0):

Just to get you started, suppose you have the name like `Charlie P` in cell `B11` of the invoice sheet, and your invoice rows start at `B15`, leaving row 14 blank. Also suppose that your time sheet has the name `timeSheet` and has the layout like in your images...

You can use these *array formulas*. Enter each of them at row 14 as indicated then press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`. Then copy that row and paste it down for a certain number of rows.

```
Formula for Date Column @ B14:
=IFERROR(INDEX(TimeSheet!$C$7:$C$999,MATCH(1, (TimeSheet!$A$7:$A$999& " "&
TimeSheet!$B$7:$B$999=$B$11)*(TimeSheet!$C$7:$C$999>B14),0)),"")

Formula for Service Column @ C14:
=IFERROR(INDEX(TimeSheet!$E$7:$E$999,MATCH(1,(TimeSheet!$A$7:$A$999& " " &
TimeSheet!$B$7:$B$999=$B$11)*(TimeSheet!$C$7:$C999=B15),0)) & " - " &
INDEX(TimeSheet!$E$7:$E$999,MATCH(1,(TimeSheet!$A$7:$A$999& " " &
TimeSheet!$B$7:$B$999=$B$11)*(TimeSheet!$C$7:$C$999=B15),0)), "")

Formula for Hours Column @ D14:
=IFERROR(INDEX(TimeSheet!$G$7:$G999,MATCH(1, (TimeSheet!$A$7:$A$999& " " &
TimeSheet!$B$7:$B$999=$B$11)*(TimeSheet!$C$7:$C$999=B15),0)),"")
```

This will get you started. You can adjust further, basically the other fields in the invoice sheet are straigtforward, i.e. `total paid = total hr * rate/hr` etc.